# 'onStateChange' event isn't triggered on page using flash player but is on a page using the HTML5 player

Tags: javascript, flash, youtube, youtube-api, html5-video

Adding an event listener to the player on a YouTube video page like this...

```
document.getElementById("movie_player").addEventListener("onStateChange", function() { console.log("STATE HAS CHANGED"); });
```

...works fine when run in the console on any video page using the HTML5 player (console output: `undefined`), but when used on a page with the Flash player (console output: `null`), the event is never triggered when the state is changed (i.e. when the video is paused or played).

For example, running the above line of code in the console on [this page](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmv1dTnhLH4) works great. The 'STATE HAS CHANGED' message appears every time the video is played or paused. However, doing the same on [this page](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJp37Rm2O-U) will result in nothing happening at all.

Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Sidenote: I am opted into the YouTube HTML5 video player (youtube.com/html5)

Comment: Just found that if I modify the code to pass the event listener the name of a function to call back instead of an inline function, it works. Can anyone shed some light on why this is?

Comment: For example: `document.getElementById("movie_player").addEventListener("onStateChange", "nameOfFunction"); function nameOfFunction() { console.log("STATE HAS CHANGED"); }`

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with Flash's ability to communicate with javascript functions. Since the events will be raised as Flash events, the flash player needs to use the ExternalInterface object to trigger javascript callbacks. Though I don't know for sure, it seems logical that, to register the callback function in flash, it needs a named function rather than an anonymous one. I may be way off, though.